Replace parts of dataframe values based on values in another dataframe
I have two dataframes in my Databricks notebook. For example, data looks like below:
df1:
id name
1  200/300A/200B
2  805/805B/500
3  22A+100B
4  200/300A/200B+22A+100B;
5  100+-805/+22A+100B;
6  ;
7  NULL

df2:
ids
805
200B
22A

I want to replace df1 names with df2 ids as 0 and remaining ones as "1". For example, wherever the data is present as 805, 200B or 22A I need to replace these values in df1 with zero else one.
df
id name
1  1/1/0
2  0/1/1
3  0+1
4  1/1/0+0+1;
5  1+-0/+0+1;
6  ;
7  NULL


Is "/", "+", ";" always the delimiter. or are there more than the mentioned one?

some times string is coming with both combination i.e. / and + together, example, 200/300A/200B+500+22A; how to solve this kind of string.

no problem. for now you can update your question with all combinations.. also mentioned what is your exact requirement or use case for doing this .. for better understanding ?

I mean why you are using spark for this usecase

The following approach collects everything from df2 into a Python list and then builds on Spark's regex lookarounds which may be difficult to maintain.
Input:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, '200/300A/200B'),
     (2, '805/805B/500'),
     (3, '22A+100B'),
     (4, '200/300A/200B+22A+100B;'),
     (5, '100+-805/+22A+100B;'),
     (6, ';'),
     (7, None)],
    ['id', 'name'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('805',), ('200B',), ('22A',)], ['ids'])

Script:
zeros = df2.agg(F.collect_set('ids')).head()[0]
for_zeros = '|'.join(zeros)
pat_for_zeros = f'(?<![\d\w])({for_zeros})(?![\w\d])'
pat_for_other = f'(?<![\d\w])(?!0([^\w\d]|$))[\d\w]+'
replaced_zeros = F.regexp_replace('name', pat_for_zeros, '0')
replaced_other = F.regexp_replace(replaced_zeros, pat_for_other, '1')
df = df1.withColumn('name', replaced_other)

df.show()
# +---+----------+
# | id|      name|
# +---+----------+
# |  1|     1/1/0|
# |  2|     0/1/1|
# |  3|       0+1|
# |  4|1/1/0+0+1;|
# |  5|1+-0/+0+1;|
# |  6|         ;|
# |  7|      NULL|
# +---+----------+


would you explain pat_for_zeros , pat_for_other will do exactly ?

They are basically for non alphanumeric symbol checking. In pat_for_zeros, when matching for the specified values, the lookarounds ensure that when values are found, they are surrounded with non alphanumeric symbols. pat_for_other as well checks the whereabouts for when any alphanumeric sequence is found and also there is a part which excludes 0 from allowed aplhanumeric sequences.

Check below code
WITH input AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        name,
        r.ids
    FROM VALUES (1 ,'200/300A/200B'),(2 ,'805/805B/500'),(3 ,'22A+100B'),(4 ,';'),(5, NULL) AS (id, name)
    JOIN ( SELECT COLLECT_LIST(ids) AS ids FROM VALUES ('805'),('200B'),('22A') AS (ids) ) r
)
SELECT 
    id,
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(name) == 1 THEN name 
             ELSE     
                transform(
                    array_distinct(
                        regexp_extract_all(name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', 0)
                    ), 
                    t -> 
                        CONCAT_WS(
                            t, 
                            transform(
                                split(name, concat('[',t,']')),
                                s -> if(array_contains(ids,s), 0, 1)
                            )
                        )
                )[0]
    END AS name
FROM input

+---+-----+
|id |name |
+---+-----+
|1  |1/1/0|
|2  |0/1/1|
|3  |0+1  |
|4  |;    |
|5  |NULL |
+---+-----+

